# Have a problem when call ooptimizer_step() in pytorch_lightning

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pytorch-lightning

I should make a model with pytorch_lightingin so I have a part for managing optimization so I call  below function

```
  def optimizer_step(self,epoch,batch_idx,optimizer,optimizer_idx,optimizer_closure=None,on_tpu=Falseusi 
             ng_native_amp=False,using_lbfgs=False,**kwargs):

    if self.trainer.global_step < 500:
        lr_scale = min(1., float(self.trainer.global_step + 1) / 500.)
        for pg in optimizer.param_groups:
            pg['lr'] = lr_scale * self.hparams.learning_rate

    ## Linear Decay
    else:
        for pg in optimizer.param_groups:
            pg['lr'] = polynomial(self.hparams.learning_rate, self.trainer.global_step, max_iter = self.max_steps)


    optimizer.step(optimizer_closure)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

but when I run

```
trainer.fit(model,dl)
```

I encounter following error

```html
MisconfigurationException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-324898bb4d9a> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer.fit(model,datamodule)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/closure.py in consume_result(self)
     49         """
     50         if self._result is None:
---> 51             raise MisconfigurationException(
     52                 "The closure hasn't been executed."
     53                 " HINT: did you call `optimizer_closure()` in your `optimizer_step` hook? It could also happen because"

MisconfigurationException: The closure hasn't been executed. HINT: did you call `optimizer_closure()` in your `optimizer_step` hook? It could also happen because the `optimizer.step(optimizer_closure)` call did not execute it internally.
```

in addition I change `optimizer_closure` without `None` but I have problem yet
I change `optimizer.step(optimizer_closure)` without any parameter `optimizer.step()` have error again